# What's the equivalent of Visual Studio's Control+Dash shortcut in WebStorm?

Tags: visual-studio, webstorm

Can't find it when I googled it

Control+Dash is a good IDE functionality, it's used when you want to go back to where the previous cursor is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Ctrl + Alt + Left`**

You can assign preferred shortcut to navigate backward action in Settings/Keymap/Main menu/Navigate/Back. Default is Ctrl+alt+Left

To get to settings Webstorm 9:
File->Settings->Appearance & Behavior->Keymap->Navigate->Back
[image]

Comment: Thanks! productivity restored :-)